# Windows Service Not starting fails with Error 1053 (The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.)

Tags: c#, .net-core, timeout, windows-services, visual-studio-2022

I use windows and Visual studio (2022) coding in c#,  to create a windows service using .Net core
the code is generated by visual studio and build by it.
it does creates two files, one called
**Program.cs** that have this content

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                 
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService< Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

and **Worker.cs** that i have modified to do the minimum but even the original fails to start

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService

    {
        static int i = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        private void writefile(string  textf)
        {
            string path = $"C:\\Temp\\{textf}.txt";

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textf);
            }
        }
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            writefile("Worker");
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            writefile("StartAsync");

            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            writefile("StopAsync");

            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        //ExecuteAsync is left empty
        protected override  Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            writefile($"ExecuteAsync{i++}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

The code above does create the intended files (and i have added this code to track the issue)

When code is Build I install the service using the command prompt
sc create MyService binPath="c:\Visual Studio\bin\debug\myservice.exe"

the directory where the .exe resides have all the .dlls , I also tried with the Release version with same error.

The event viewer do not show any other information but the same error.

I have tried also to use my own account as startup account for the service with same result

I have also tried to change the timeout (registry) for services (\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicePipeTimeout & \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice\StartTimeout) to a bigger value , but they are just ignored and 30 seconds is always used.

Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this the solution that worked for me, on the Worker.cs a call was  missing     

   IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                 
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService< Worker>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService()  // this code is required
    .Build();
    
    await host.RunAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove await inside Program.

See section "Rewrite the Program class":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: I saw, it threw a light to my brain, yet, same behaviour, still timing out.

Comment: ok Dan, the await does make the issue to go away, yet it does fit with the coding in the Program, where all the methods are executed , also the link you posted contains the solution is there, the call to .UseWindowsService() is missing